# Uncertainty in values predicted using a linear regression

Tags: regression, standard-error, linear, uncertainty, error-propagation

I am quite new to statistical analysis, so this question might seem a bit obvious. My problem is the following. I have performed a simple linear regression between two sets of values without uncertainty, resulting in a regression equation of the form
$$
y = ax+b.
$$
I have calculated the uncertainty in the slope, $\delta a$, the uncertainty in the intersection, $\delta b$, and the standard error of the regression $\delta y_\text{reg}$.

My question is the following: given an independent point $\hat{x}$ and its prediction using the regression line $\hat{y}$, how can a good estimate of the uncertainty in $\hat{y}$ be calculated? I have two approaches in mind:

- Using uncertainty propagation to calculate
  $$
  \delta \hat{y} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial a}\right)^2 (\delta a)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial b}\right)^2 (\delta b)^2} = \sqrt{\hat{x}^2 (\delta a)^2 + (\delta b)^2}.
  $$
- Estimating the error in $\hat{y}$ as twice standard error of the regression, so $\delta \hat{y} = 2*\delta y_\text{reg}$ (95% prediction interval).
- A combination of the preceding two.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: You might be interested in [conformal prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_prediction)